# Angular daterangepicker - min date on "FROM"

Tags: angularjs, daterangepicker

i need to set "from" and "to" date. I want on "from" set only from tomorow or any date in future, not in past. And after select start date, then enable "to" picker and set end date, but with min day range. And show day range in dom.
I try github solution from official page, but everything is from bootstrap daterange not for angular daterange. Thnx
here is html code

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <p class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" 
                                   class="form-control" 
                                   datetime-picker="yyyy-MM-dd"
                                   ng-model="ctrl.picker4.date"
                                   is-open="ctrl.picker4.open" 
                                   enable-time="false" 
                                   datepicker-options="ctrl.picker4.datepickerOptions" 
                                   myformat
                                   />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.openCalendar($event, 'picker4')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 col-xs-2 control-label" style="color: #fff">To</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <p class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" 
                                   class="form-control" 
                                   datetime-picker="yyyy-MM-dd"
                                   ng-model="ctrl.picker5.date"
                                   is-open="ctrl.picker5.open" 
                                   enable-time="false" 
                                   datepicker-options="ctrl.picker5.datepickerOptions" 
                                   myformat
                                   />
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ctrl.openCalendar($event, 'picker5')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and here is controller

```
  //date picker
    var that = this;

 // date picker


 // min date picker
    this.picker4 = {
        date: new Date(),
        datepickerOptions: {
            showWeeks: true,
            startingDay: 1,
            maxDate: null
        }
    };

 // max date picker
    this.picker5 = {
        date: new Date(),
        datepickerOptions: {
            showWeeks: true,
            startingDay: 1,
            minDate: null
        }
    };
    /*
     // set date for max picker, 10 days in future
     this.picker5.date.setDate(this.picker5.date.getDate() + 10);

     */

 // when closed picker
    this.picker13 = {
        date: new Date(),
        closed: function (args) {
            that.closedArgs = args;
        }
    };



    this.openCalendar = function (e, picker) {
        that[picker].open = true;
    };
// watch min and max dates to calculate difference
    var unwatchMinMaxValues = $scope.$watch(function () {
        return [that.picker4, that.picker5, that.picker10, that.picker11];
    }, function () {
 // min max dates
        that.picker4.datepickerOptions.maxDate = that.picker5.date;
        that.picker5.datepickerOptions.minDate = that.picker4.date;
        if (that.picker4.date && that.picker5.date) {
            var diff = that.picker4.date - that.picker5.date;
            that.dayRange = Math.round(Math.abs(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 *         24)))
        } else {
            that.dayRange = 'n/a';
        }


    }, true);


 // destroy watcher
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        unwatchMinMaxValues();
    });
```

Comment: <input min="'2014-02-23'" ...  Could you try this?

Comment: hi, but i need set date for tomorow. Always one day+

Answer (score 1):

if you are using date ranges better to use daterangepicker (http://www.daterangepicker.com/). This will avoid hassles to write validation code for start date and end date. If you select Start date you will be able to select End Date after the Start Date only. no need to write validation code.

Comment: hi thnx for answers. But i dont know how to use this with angularjs? thnx

Comment: use it just as any other jquery. assign it to class or id of textbox. Once you are able to open the daterangepicker for textbox you should be able to get the value of textbox in the controller. since it has both start and end date split them using pop and shift and use accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

i have using the directive for date picker for start date minimum `minDate:new Date().getDate+0,` and maximum `maxDate:new Date().getDate+30`  ihave using `bootstrap-datetimepicker`

```
module.directive('examdatepicker1', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var currentYear=new Date().getFullYear();
        var finalYear=parseInt(new Date().getFullYear())+1;
        $(element).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            yearRange: currentYear+":"+finalYear,
            minDate:new Date().getDate+0,
            //maxDate:new Date().getDate+30,
            onClose: function(date){
                //var datearray = date.split("/");
                //var newdate = datearray[1] + '/' + datearray[0] + '/' + datearray[2];
                var selectedDate = new Date(date);
                var msecsInADay = 86400000;
                var minimum = new Date(selectedDate.getTime());
                //var maximum = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + (30*msecsInADay));
                $("#end_exam_date").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minimum );
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

and for second datepicker

```
module.directive('examdatepicker2', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var currentYear=new Date().getFullYear();
        var finalYear=parseInt(new Date().getFullYear())+1;
        $(element).datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            yearRange: currentYear+":"+finalYear
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

In Html

```
<input class="form-control bg-color-white" id="end_exam_date" name='end_exam_date' ng-model="end_exam_date" class="form-control" examdatepicker1 readonly required>
```

Comment: i try this, i added in html <examdatepicker1></examdatepicker1> ... But i get error $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: use examdatepicker1 as an attribute

Comment: use `<input class="form-control bg-color-white" id="end_exam_date" name='end_exam_date' ng-model="end_exam_date" class="form-control" examdatepicker1 readonly required>` @Arter

Answer (score 1):

here is simply solution. We need to delete this from controller

```
 that.picker4.datepickerOptions.maxDate = that.picker5.date;
```

and everything work. Now i dont need enable end date because this is working solution. But from code in my first question, i need to show daterange. I make code but i think, because i change date format, dayRange can not calculate.

```
 if (that.picker4.date && that.picker5.date) {
        var diff = that.picker4.date - that.picker5.date;
        that.dayRange = Math.round(Math.abs(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 *         24)))
    } else {
        that.dayRange = 'n/a';
    }
```

Please take a look on code. Thnx

Comment: Ok fine if is it enough for you its ok any other help will be welcomed